# Decode byte string to Cyrillic in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, decode

I have a byte string like this, it should be `Сравнение` in Cyrillic characters:

```
a = b'&#1057;&#1088;&#1072;&#1074;&#1085;&#1077;&#1085;&#1080;&#1077;'
```

Decoding it into UTF-8 doesn't help:

```
a = b'&#1057;&#1088;&#1072;&#1074;&#1085;&#1077;&#1085;&#1080;&#1077;'
a.decode("utf-8") # prints same &#1057;&#1088;... string
```

Which encoding is this and how to decode the string?

I'm using Google Colab with Python 3.10.12.

[This online decoder](https://www.online-decoder.com/bg) after applying auto-decode says it must be decoded from UTF-8 to UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`html.unescape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape):

```py
import html

a = b"&#1057;&#1088;&#1072;&#1074;&#1085;&#1077;&#1085;&#1080;&#1077;"
decoded_string = html.unescape(a.decode("utf-8"))

print(decoded_string)
```

Prints:

```
Сравнение
```